# the function clone() does not work in Internet Explorer ( works in firefox)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, clone

I would like to clone item of type (sortable-accordion), which u can see here:
http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/sortable.html.

I add cloned Item using the function clone(), as you can see here:

```
$("#cloneElement").click(function(){    
  var newElem = $('#acc-0').clone(true).attr('id', 'acc-1').addClass("clonedDiv");
 newElem.insertBefore($("#acc-0"));
}
```

the div I clone looks like this:

```
<div id="acc-0">
  <h3>
    <a id="section" href="#">Section </a>
  </h3> 
  <div>
  <fieldset  style="clear: both">
    <input type="text" name="section[]" id="section" value="">  
    <textarea name="content[]" id="content" class="text ui-corner-all"></textarea> 
   </fieldset>                          
 </div>
</div>
```

And this is jquery button I use to add new element

```
<input type="radio" id="cloneElement" name="cloneElement" />
```

When i click on the button, the element will be cloned and added and I can see it in firefox.
This does not work in Internet Exploerer. When I click on the button nothing happend :( Why it does not work in Exploerer?

Comment: Your `<fieldset>` tag is unclosed. It'd be worth a try to add the `</fieldset>` and see if that helps.

Comment: thank you but this is not the problem

Comment: [It's working fine in IE9.](http://jsfiddle.net/Pointy/L2cn8/) Also IE8.

Comment: Works fine in IE for me too, once I fixed the syntax error in the javascript.

Comment: It works anyhow, when I change the type of button from "radio" to "button", how to explain this? :( Is there any way to get it working with buton of type "radio"?